# How Do I Reset a Tripp Lite PDU

Tags: power-distribution-unit, reset

I am working on reselling a tripp lite PDU for my company, and I need to know how to reset it to default factory settings. In other threads it says to push the reset pin, however there is no pinhole on the unit to push. Please if anybody has any ideas I am working with a Tripp Lite PDUMV30HVNET. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The reset pin on that unit is near the panel with the Ethernet and Serial interfaces. [See the manual](http://www.tripplite.com/shared/techdoc/Owners-Manual/933093.pdf).

[image]

If you previously had connectivity to the unit, you can also do this from the web and serial interfaces. But in the end, it's a PDU. Is there any company-specific information contained within?

Comment: That is the thing... There is no pin on the unit. The manual that is on the product page shows an incorrect image for the ports on the back. So no, there is no reset pin which I can use. Got any other ideas?

Comment: I'd 1). Call Tripp-Lite support or 2). grab a serial cable and perform a software reset or 3). just sell the unit as-is... Let the new owner figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

[User manual for PDUMV30HVNET](http://www.tripplite.com/switched-pdu-30a-208v-240v-0u-vertical-c13-c19-outlets-nema-l6-30p-single-phase%7EPDUMV30HVNET/)

Assuming this is your unit, there looks like a little reset button above the Config port.  Barring that working (try holding it in with a paperclip for 20 seconds), you should be able to connect a console cable into that Config port, and connect using a terminal.

Details:

> Use the console cable. Plug into a machine and launch a terminal program. Reboot the PDU. When you see the device post it will display the config and allow you to press a key within 5 seconds to change the config.
>
> The default Root Password is TrippLite.
> From there you will be prompted with questions.
> One of them asks if you want to Restore Factory Defaults. Say Yes.

[Source here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?s=ad0ddd9adc54d2d5f0a98e7ba2c4f5af&p=7865785&postcount=7).  Good luck!

Comment: I ended up calling customer support, and they told me that I would need a proprietary cable that only they could supply to me in order to connect to said PDU. Which sucks big time. Also, there is not any company specific info on the PDU, but I work for a refurbishing center and we are attempting to reset this PDU to its factory defaults in order to resell it. Anybody got any other ideas on how I could do this while I am still missing the cable?

Comment: I had assumed that it was a standard serial (null modem) cable.  If it's not, it should be one of these:

http://www.tripplite.com/products/series/sid/777

They look to be about $10 or less.  Hopefully your business can absorb this cost, if necessary :)  Also, they seem to be widely available online, not just from the manufacturer, that's good.